# What TimestampsAndWatermarksTransformation class does in assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In the following code

```java
public SingleOutputStreamOperator<T> assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        WatermarkStrategy<T> watermarkStrategy) {
    final WatermarkStrategy<T> cleanedStrategy = clean(watermarkStrategy);
    // match parallelism to input, to have a 1:1 source -> timestamps/watermarks relationship
    // and chain
    final int inputParallelism = getTransformation().getParallelism();
    final TimestampsAndWatermarksTransformation<T> transformation =
            new TimestampsAndWatermarksTransformation<>(
                    "Timestamps/Watermarks",
                    inputParallelism,
                    getTransformation(),
                    cleanedStrategy);
    getExecutionEnvironment().addOperator(transformation);
    return new SingleOutputStreamOperator<>(getExecutionEnvironment(), transformation);
}
```

The `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()` receives the main stream and assigns timestamps and watermarks based on the strategy specified in params, at the end, it will return `SingleOutputStreamOperator` which is the updated stream with timestamps and watermarks generated.

My question is, what `TimestampsAndWatermarksTransformation` does here (internally) and what is the effect of this line `getExecutionEnvironment().addOperator(transformation);` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on a stream, this code adds an operator to the job graph to do the timestamp extraction and watermark generation. This is wiring things up so that the specified watermarking will actually get done.

Internally there are two types of Transformation: (1) physical transformations, such as `map` or `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks`, which alter the stream records, and (2) logical transformations, such as `union`, that only affect the topology.

Comment: Thank you, David. I've got the idea. Could you please recommend a resource to understand the flink internals?

Comment: The source code reading notes at https://blog.jrwang.me/tags/flink/ are helpful (I read them via google translate). And on some topics there are excellent blog posts and/or Flink Forward talks you can refer to.